# AWS::Errors::MissingCredentialsError using paperclip and aws-s3 in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload image at aws.

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  attr_accessible :image
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "640x480>", 
                                     :thumb => "100x100#"},
  :storage => :s3,
   :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
  :path => ":attachment/:id/:style.:extension",
  :bucket => 'yourbucket'
end
```

s3.yml

```
development:
  access_key_id: xxxxxxxx

   secret_code: xxxxx
```

I am getting a message

```
 AWS::Errors::MissingCredentialsError in PostsController#create

Missing Credentials.

 Unable to find AWS credentials.  You can configure your AWS credentials
 a few different ways:

 * Call AWS.config with :access_key_id and :secret_access_key

 * Export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY to ENV

* On EC2 you can run instances with an IAM instance profile and credentials 
 will be auto loaded from the instance metadata service on those
  instances.

* Call AWS.config with :credential_provider.  A credential provider should
either include AWS::Core::CredentialProviders::Provider or respond to
the same public methods.

= Ruby on Rails
```

In a Ruby on Rails application you may also specify your credentials in 
   the following ways:

- Via a config initializer script using any of the methods mentioned above
  (e.g. RAILS_ROOT/config/initializers/aws-sdk.rb).
- Via a yaml configuration file located at RAILS_ROOT/config/aws.yml.
  This file should be formated like the default RAILS_ROOT/config/database.yml
  file.

I believe I am doing the last step.

Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.3'
gem 'mysql'
gem 'koala'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'aws-s3'
gem 'aws-sdk'
```

Answer (score 7):

The following worked for me:

1. Create a file in your initializers called aws.rb
2. Put in the following in your aws.rb file:

   ```
   AWS.config(
   access_key_id: 'your_access_key',
   secret_access_key: 'your_secret_access_key')
   ```
3. Then my paperclip options looks like this:

   ```
   has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" },       
   :default_url => "missing_:style.png", :default_url => 'missing_:style.png', :storage =>   
   :s3, :bucket => "<my_bucket>"
   ```

Comment: This definitely works for the 'first pass' of getting paper up and running, and was what i was looking.  Caveat is that the environmental variable method linked in TJ Sherrill's answer is the canonical 'correct' answer.

Comment: I would like to add with the new sdk you'll have to use Aws.config.update({}) as config is no longer a method but a hash.

Comment: I suggest using environment parameters... putting this in a config file should be avoided, and especially don't commit this into source control. You do not want this type of secret information in the source code.