# Setting aws client with figaro in rails.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I am setting the aws credentials on my application.yml

```
AWS_KEY: 'myKey'
AWS_SECRET: 'mySecret'
```

Then

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new
```

successfully returns a client, but when I am trying to fetch an object

```
resp = s3.get_object(bucket:'my-bucket', key:'myFile.txt')
```

I am getting the following error.

```
Aws::Errors::MissingCredentialsError:
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223762/awserrorsmissingcredentialserror-using-paperclip-and-aws-s3-in-rails-3-1

Comment: I don't think this is the same problem.